# Is there a way to eliminate flyout menus when adding a post?

Tags: posts, images, menus

It seems like each new version of wordpress adds more intermediate menus and menu options than the previous. Particularly heinous examples include the Preview button with its form-factor checkboxes, requiring a second-click to accomplish the original function, and the "Select Image" option which instead of defaulting to the media library as it used to now expands a flyout window with no fewer than 4 alternates (and growing): Google Photos, Pexels, Openverse, and Jetpack Mobile App -- 3 of which I have no idea what they are and certainly do not belong on a main context menu.

The question is: can these flyout menus be eliminated or defaults set so that I do not need to click, and re-click, every time I add an image or look at a post?

Comment: Do you have Jetpack installed?  This seems like it's a module you can enable/disable in Jetpack.  I just went and double checked several sites that are running the newest version of WP, without any elaborate plugins, and none of them have he behaviour you're describing.